# Recursively trigger $animate.addClass animations

Tags: angularjs, css, ng-animate, animate.css

Hi I am trying to setup a looping animation for my project. I am attempting to setup a recursively triggered animation with $animate. It looks like this within the link function of one of my directives:

```
            function startLoopAnimation(count) {
              if(loopSkip === false) {

                animateLoop().then(function() {
                  count--;                 
                  if(count > 0) {
                    startLoopAnimation(count);
                  }
                });
              }

              function animateLoop() {
                return $animate.addClass(element,
                    'wobble ' +
                    'linear' +
                    ' duration-' + scope.config.animation.loop.duration * 10
                );
              }
            }
```

The function is called but the animation is never triggered a second time.
 What is the best way to setup an asynchronously triggered animation like this?

This also has to work on older versions on android, so performance is key. Also, using 'infinite' animation-iteration-count is not an option.

UPDATE: I provided my solution for this specific case, however I would still like to know why this didn't work and how I could have made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my code by simplifying it. As long as I have access to the amount of loop iterations there should be (which I do), I can just set 'animation-iteration-count' to loop the animation the correct amount of times.

```
function animateLoop(loopCount) {
            return $animate.addClass(element,
                scope.config.animation.loop.animation + ' ' +
                scope.config.animation.loop.timingFunction +
                ' duration-' +
                scope.config.animation.loop.duration * 10 +
                    ' iteration-count-' + loopCount
            );
          }
```

I also used a LESS loop to generate the iteration classes (just as I had with duration):

```
.iterationLoop(@counter: 100) when (@counter > 0) {
  .iteration-count-@{counter} {
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: @counter;
    animation-iteration-count: @counter;
  }

  .iterationLoop((@counter - 1));

}

.iterationLoop();
```